# Textfeild's keyboard hide bottomsheet in Flutter v2

Tags: flutter, dart, bottom-sheet

Why my `bottomsheet` is disappearing upon opening keyboard while clicking `textfeild`? I tried many solutions but none of them is working properly.

I have nothing much to add just trying to complete the words criteria.
"It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details".

```dart
Container(
     padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
     horizontal: deviceSize.width * 0.1),
          child: InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                  showAddressBottomSheet(context);
              },
                child: ...// Button style
           ),
```

```dart
 void showAddressBottomSheet(BuildContext _context) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      context: _context,
      isScrollControlled: true,
      elevation: 20,
      builder: (context) {
        return AddAddressView(
          callback: (val) => setState(() => _addrSelectedTitle = val),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

**Actual Buttom sheet**

```dart
class AddAddressView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AddAddressViewState createState() => _AddAddressViewState();
}

class _AddAddressViewState extends State<AddAddressView> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return SingleChildScrollView(
         child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(30),
               child: ListView(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(......),
                    TextField(
                        autofocus: true,
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize:15),
                        controller: widget.controller,
                        ..........
                     ),
                   ),
                 ),
               ),
             },
          }
```

[image]

Comment: I assume you are on Flutter 2? I just updated and we are getting a similar issue. This seems like something to report to flutter.

Comment: @Cadoo I've reported this issue https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/79128

Answer (score 2):

I have seen this issue before and since you have posted a reproduction of your actual code, I'm assuming this padding value exists somewhere in your widget tree

```
padding: EdgeInsets.only(
          bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom,
        ),
```

In older versions of flutter, this padding was required for the bottom sheet to move up when the keyboard is in view. They have however been fixed and you don't need to apply the padding anymore and the framework will handle it. Otherwise there will be twice as much padding as seen in your case.

Comment: So mean to say that i should give `container` inside `SingleChildScrollView` this padding value `EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),`. I tried it but it is not working either ?

Comment: What I'm saying is you should not have this padding value anywhere inside `AddAddressView()`. Please check to see if you have it already. If yes then remove it.

Comment: @beckzila no I don't have this padding value anywhere inside `AddAddressView()`